# How can I make an entire row clickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using wordpress and beaver builder. I need to make an entire row clickable. Basically "despre" goes to "despre page" "servicii" goes to "servicii page"and so on.
The website is [this](https://contarealserv.ro)

I got this code from a guy but unfortunately It's not working on mobile version.

```js
$('#aflamaimult')
  .css('cursor', 'pointer')
  .on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).css('opacity', '.75')
  })
  .on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).css('opacity', '1')
      .on('click', function() {
        window.location.href = "https://google.com";
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Post the relevant HTML in your question please

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem. Also see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please update the snippet I made you with relevant HTML and CSS

Comment: [More examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=mouseenter+mobile+site:stackoverflow.com)